# When does it make sense to use Terminal Service Gateway?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, terminal-server

We've been using [XRDP](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/) which was developed by one of the fellows who used to work at my company, but I'm pretty sure it's not being too actively developed any more and we're running out of people who care enough to administer Linux (except for me).
So I was wondering whether Terminal Server Gateway can do the same thing, XRDP can connect me via VNC or RDesktop to any machine inside the network it's running on.  It seems utterly insecure as a replacement for a VPN, but it works and is pretty cool.  Is a terminal server gateway pretty much the same thing?  and could someone show me where the stinking control panel is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal Services Gateway makes sense when you want give secure, encrypted access to internal resources from the outside (internet) **without having to establish VPN connections**. TS Gateway uses Remote Desktop Protocol over HTTPS.

Resources include terminal servers, terminal servers running RemoteApp programs, or computers with Remote Desktop enabled.

It will **simplify your network administration** if your company is hosting Terminal Services–based applications or if you want to make PCs that run Remote Desktop available  from outside your network perimeter.

Using the snap-in console for the TS gateway you can define authorization policies like

- which user groups and computer groups are allowed to connect
- whether client computers must be members of Active Directory security groups
- whether device and disk redirection is allowed

etc.

Premise: you'll need Windows Server 2008.

Comment: Yes, it is filthy easy to setup.